# mocha can't seem to recognize file system

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

i am new to tests, i can hit my end points with postman with no issue but mocha doesn't seem to recognize my variables that depend on the file system, it says callBackPath and appPath are not defined

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let version = req.url.match(/\/api\/(v[0-9]+).*/) || [];
  const {
    readdirSync
  } = require('fs');

  const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, './api');
  const getDirectories = srcPath => fs.readdirSync(srcPath).filter(file => fs.statSync(path.join(srcPath, file)).isDirectory());

  const lastDir = getDirectories(dirPath)[getDirectories(dirPath).length - 1];
  version = version[1] || '';
  if (version != '') {
    const appPath = path.join(__dirname, `./api/${version}/index.js`);
    const callBackPath = path.join(__dirname, `./api/${lastDir}/index.js`);
    console.log(callBackPath);
    if (!fs.existsSync(appPath)) {

      return res.status(404).send({
        message: 'It\'s not us, sorry we can\'t find this end point'
      });
    }
    require(appPath)(app);
  } else {
    require(callBackPath)(app);
  }
  next();
});

app.listen(config.port);
console.log(`Server started on port ${
      config.port
    }`);

  module.exports = app;
```

mocha code

```
chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.should();

describe('user', ()=>{
  describe('POST /', ()=> {
    it("should create new user", done=>{
      chai.request(app)
        .post('/register')
        .end((err, res) => {
          res.should.have.status(200);
          res.should.be.a('object');
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the post url in Mocha is correct? It doesn't match the version extracting regex, so version is empty

Comment: @jro huh true but i think the other callBackPath is defined though

Comment: since version is not defined, callbackPath won't be defined

Comment: @jro sorry had it working, didn't pay attention thanks